# Serial or serials

Tags: word-choice

I am  confused by "series" and "serial" in this sentence.

Can I use either A: "I  watched a new episode of "The Medici" TV series or B:  "I watched a new episode of "The Medici" serial"?  But not "serials" instead of "serial". Right?

Comment: Here, series and serial are both singular. You are watching an episode in a single series, or of a single serial.

Comment: Sorry, do you mean  A means a new episode of "one" particular series of The Medici.  And B means a new episode of one particular  serial/the narrative  The Medici?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a subtle distinction between *series* and *serial* when used for television (at least in the United States). I'm not sure that the dictionary definitions call out the difference.

A *serial* implies a continuing story, where each episode has definite continuity with those immediately before and after, and missing a group of episodes can leave you with a "gap" in the story and your understanding of it.

A *series* does not carry that implication. Each episode of a series can stand alone as a story, and you don't need to know "what has gone before" to be able to fully understand the story in *this* episode.

As examples, *Star Trek* or *House* is a *series*. Many of the 'soap operas' ("daytime TV"), such as *The Young and the Restless* or *Days of Our Lives* are *serials*.